# How to save an array of dictionary to plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Plist just wont save save itself...

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Please help.

```
NSString *factorsFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"factors" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *factorsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:factorsFile];

NSMutableDictionary *dictFactor = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictFactor setObject:self.nameField.text forKey:@"Factor"];
[dictFactor setObject:self.rankField.text forKey:@"Rank"];

NSLog(@"%@",dictFactor);

[factorsArray addObject:dictFactor];

NSLog(@"%@",factorsArray);

if([factorsArray writeToFile:factorsFile atomically:YES]){
    NSLog(@"lalal");
}
```

This code is able to go inside the last if loop but the plist remains unchanged... Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't write/modify files in the app bundle.

**You can, however, perform a Google search** for the expression ["ios plist write to bundle unchanged"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+plist+write+to+bundle+unchanged), and you can have a look at the first four results. They're all identical/duplicate StackOverflow-questions:

[plist writing data inside dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497517/plist-writing-data-inside-dictionary)

[write into plist file using NSDictionary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433598/write-into-plist-file-using-nsdictionary-object)

[Not Able to write Boolean in plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593627/not-able-to-write-boolean-in-plist-file)

[writeToFile fails on iphone but works on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092026/writetofile-fails-on-iphone-but-works-on-simulator)